# Set a multiline string as defaultValue in react-ace Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, react-ace

When using the react-ace (Ace Editor) library, I find myself in the need to define the `defaultValue` property as a code block in the JSX format (the editor mode I have left in JavaScript), like this:

```
<div style={{height: "100%", width:"100%"}}>
  <AceEditor
      mode="javascript"
      theme="github"
      onChange={this.onChange}
      name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
      defaultValue="export default function MyComponent({ children }) {..."
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      editorProps={{
          $blockScrolling: true
      }}
  />
</div>
```

When declaring `defaultValue` to get something like this:

```
export default function MyComponent({ children }) {
    return (
    <>
      <header>
        <a>
          <Image
            priority
            className={utilStyles.borderCircle}
            height={108}
            width={108}
            alt={name}
          />
        </a>
        <h2 className={utilStyles.headingLg}>
          <a className={utilStyles.colorInherit}>{name}</a>
        </h2>
      </header>
      <main>{children}</main>
        {!home && (
          <div className={styles.backToHome}>
            <a>← Home</a>
          </div>
        )}
    </>
  )
}
```

The editor returns...

[image: Code editor description]

How can I get a multiline string into the editor as a default value?

Comment: I've also tried to use expressions like '\n' or <br>but it still doesn't work, I can conclude that it's all about doing a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template literals to do the multiline statements.
In the official docs of AceEditor mentioned that you can pass a string for **value** attribute which should be reflected in the editor so when you pass a string inside " " it should not take new line so, when you use template literals ie,**``` ${``} ```**  we can give multiline sentences

so, its similar to how we pass a value in react to attributes

**attribute-name = {"here we specify what should be the value"}**

as in our case it should be a string which can be in multiple line

so **attribute-name = {``` ${``} ```}**

Example:

```
value={`${`
//firstline
//secondline
...
//n line`}`}
```

reference :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.